# These 3 matrices will not compile!

Tags: matrices, sharelatex

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}
    f(X_{1})\\
    \vdots\\
    f(X_{m})
\end{bmatrix}
\mathcal{N} $\sim$ \left(\begin{bmatrix}
    m(X_{1})\\
    \vdots\\
    m(X_{m})
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
     \kappa(X_{1},X_{1}) & \cdots & \kappa(X_{1},X_{m}) \\
     \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
     \kappa(X_{m},X_{1}) & \cdots & \kappa(X_{m},X_{m})
   \end{bmatrix}\right) 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

They are three matrixes , i am doing my project on share latex but this will not compile (fast) or at all sometimes, I even bought subscription to speed it up , but still nothing happens. Is the problem somewhere with my syntax?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Remove the `$` signs around `\sim`; you are already in math mode.

Comment: @gernot thank you sir, this worked! I am so blind sometimes!

Comment: By the way, why are you using `aligned` here? There is just one line, you have no alignment points. Unless you've left out parts for the sake of the example, I'd remove `\begin{aligned}` and `\end{aligned}`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem, which is solved in the comments, was caused by some unneeded and unloved `$` signs